# how to manipulate data more efficiently?

Tags: plot

What's the best way to use a data set in LaTeX? More specifically, plotting a Lagrange interpolation polynomial without having to copy paste the values one by one. (Something like arrays in Python, for example)

Comment: Without have a more concrete example of what kind of data you're dealing with, it'll be hard for others to help you.  How do you intend to 'use' it?  Do you want to plot or tabulate it?  or do you need to use it as part of a macro?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you want to do. Have a look at e.g. `pgfplots` or `pst-plot` for plotting stuff. You cannot use a python array directly anyway. Well, you can use the `pythontex` package, but that's a slightly different story.